# Finding a specific ratio in an unsorted array. Time complexity

Tags: algorithm, optimization, complexity-theory, big-o, mergesort

This is a homework assignment.

The goal is to present an algorithm in pseudocode that will search an array of numbers (doesn't specify if integers or >0) and check if the ratio of any two numbers equals a given x. Time complexity must be under O(nlogn).

My idea was to mergesort the array (O(nlogn) time) and then if |x| > 1 start checking for every number in desending order (using a binary traversal algorithm). The check should also take O(logn) time for each number, with a worst case of n checks gives a total of O(nlogn). If I am not missing anything this should give us a worst case of O(nlogn) + O(nlogn) = O(nlogn), within the parameters of the assignment.

I realize that it doesn't really matter where I start checking the ratios after sorting, but the time cost is amortized by 1/2).

Is my logic correct? Is there a faster algorithm?

An example in case it isn't clear:

Given an array { 4, 9, 2, 1, 8, 6 }

If we want to seach for a ratio of 2:

1. Mergesort { 9, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1 }
2. Since the given ratio is >1 we will search from left to right.

2a. First number is 9. Checking 9 / 4 > 2. Checking 9/6 < 2 Next Number.
2b. Second number is 8. Checking 8 / 4 = 2. DONE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of your algorithm is O(*n*²), because after sorting the array, you iterate over each element (up to *n* times) and in each iteration you execute up to *n* - 1 divisions.

Instead, after sorting the array, iterate over each element, and in each iteration divide the element by the ratio, then see if the result is contained in the array:

- division: O(1)
- search in sorted list: O(log *n*)
- repeat for each element: *n* times

Results in time complexity O(*n* log *n*)

In your example:

- 9/2 = 4.5 (not found)
- 8/2 = 4 (found)

Comment: Can you explain how the algorithm is O(n^2)?  I don't see how this does as many divisions as you claim it does.

Comment: Imagine your array is {9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1}: by 9, you'll make 5 divisions, by 7 you'll make 4, by 5, you'll make 3...

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the algorithm.  My understanding of the OP's approach was (1) sort everything, then (2) for each array element n, binary search for rn and n / r in the array.  As a result, the number of divisions is only O(log n) per element, not O(n) per element.  That seems like it only does O(n log n) work.  Did I misinterpret what the OP suggested?

Comment: That's the correct approach indeed. My suggestion was to just search for n / r, in both cases the complexity is O(*n* log *n*)

Comment: I guess I'm confused because I think that's what the OP's algorithm is, which is why I'm confused about how it takes O(n^2) time.

Comment: If I understand your example, the ratio should be 2. So starting at 9, you calculate 9*2=18 (not found), then 9/2=4.5 (not found), then 8*2=16 (not found), and then 8/2=4 (found, done). I guess tha's what your OP was suggesting.

Comment: Oh, I thought that the OP was checking for 9/2, 9 * 2, then 7/2, 7*2, then 5/2, 5 * 2, etc., not starting at the largest value and counting downward.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21908/discussion-between-ft1-and-templatetypedef)

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the general idea. Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: After reading both answers, I see this is not the same answer as I suggested. Is there a difference in (exponential) complexity? I realize that doing the division once, then searching for a match is obviously better than dividing each pair and then checking against the 'x', but if the time gain is linear, don't we still consider it to be O(nlogn) ?

Comment: I now realize you had answered my question. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 2):

The analysis you have presented is correct and is a perfectly good way to solve this problem.  Sorting does work in time O(n log n), and 2n binary searches also takes O(n log n) time.  That said, I don't think you want to use the term "amortized" here, since that refers to a different type of analysis.

As a hint for how to speed up your solution a bit, the general idea of your solution is to make it possible to efficiently query, for any number, whether that number exists in the array.  That way, you can just loop over all numbers and look for anything that would make the ratio work.  However, if you use an auxiliary data structure outside the array that supports fast access, you can possibly whittle down your runtime at the cost of increasing the memory usage.  Try thinking about what data structures support very fast access (say, O(1) lookups) and see if you can use any of them here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am still an undergraduate, and any misuse of technical terms is (I hope) forgiven. If I understand correctly (and probably have to lookup a few sources: I create a hashtable for the values, divide the current number by the required ratio "x" and check to see if this n/x exists? O(1) access in a hash implies no collisions, the question is, parsing the data to create a perfect hash function would probably raise the complexity. Can this be solved under O(nlogn)?

Comment: @GCon- If you use a standard hash table, then the *expected* runtime for a lookup will be O(1), so the *expected* runtime of the algorithm will be O(n).  Most hash tables have this runtime occur with high probability, so the odds of degenerating to something like O(n log n) are low.  However, if you are concerned about this, one option would be to have a hybrid strategy where you use the hash table, and if the number of collisions exceeds what looks "reasonable" then fall back on the O(n log n) solution.  That said, the odds of this occurring are so low it's usually not worth worrying about.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would also like to ask - probably beside the point (but I am sure it doesn't merit a new question: What is the exact definition - in algorithm analysis - of amortization? I was under the impression that simplifying the run time (but not necessarily by an order of magnitude) counted as amortization. As in using a guard node for BST lookup has the same avarage time, but one less evaluation for each node?

Comment: @GCon- Amortization is when you analyze an algorithm or data structure by looking at the total amount of work done across all operations rather than any one individual operation.  For example, appending a value to a dynamic array might take O(n) time in the worst case (if you have to double the array and copy all the old values over), but if you look at the aggregate total of all the work done adding n elements to a dynamic array the runtime is only O(n), not O(n^2), because the O(n) operations happen so infrequently.  Decreasing the work by a constant factor is good, but isn't amortization.

Answer (score 2):

to solve this problem, only O(nlgn) is enough

step 1, sort the array. that cost O(nlgn)

step 2, check whether the ratio exists, this step only needs o(n)

u just need two pointers, one points to the first element(smallest one), another points to the last element(biggest one).

calculate the ratio.

if the ratio is bigger than the specified one, move the second pointer to its previous element.

if the ratio is smaller than the specified one, move the first pointer to its next element.

repeat the above steps until:

1. u find the exact ratio, or
2. either the first pointer reaches the end, or the second point reaches the beginning

Comment: As far as I know, O(nlogn) + O(nlogn) == O(nlogn) + O(n).
Is there any gain from using this approch?

Comment: @GCon of course this approch is better. if you have a large quantity of queries, say m queries, this approch has time complexity of O(n*lg(n))+O(n*m), the other approches in this post cost O(n*lg(n))+O(n*lg(n)*m). if m>>n, O(n*lg(n)) part can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Build a hashmap of this array. Time Cost: O(n)

(2) For every element a[i], search a[i]*x in HashMap. Time Cost: O(n).

Total Cost: O(n)